# Redirecting whole website

Tags: redirect

So I redirect my old website to a new one using this redirect rule which I found here.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/ [L,R]
```

The problem is when users enter a page on the old site like `www.oldsite.com/something.html` it jumps to `www.newsite.com/something.html`. What I need is that all pages no matter what, redirect to `http://www.newsite.com/`. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/ [L,R]
```

is what you want. The effect you're describing is

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R]
```

which is not the same thing. If you're editing the configuration through some editor or website, it might be "interpreting" what it thinks you want instead of what you have entered.

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work for me.  (The query string continues to be passed.)

Comment: I just double checked it on Apache 2.2, works. What are you running?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/.*$ http://www.newsite.com/? [L,R]
```

The "?" will kill any other query string.

Comment: I'd suggest "R=301" for SEO, but this is the correct solution.

Comment: It work fine on index page, but on other pages shows me a google message `Oops! This link appears to be broken.` error on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Umm off the top of my head try something like this..

Edit the vhost and use

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.newsite.com/
```

whereby your just redirecting the whole "oldsite" to the "newsite"

The idea is just redirect the base of oldsite.com to newsite.com before anything else right??

This might also work

```
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.newsite.com [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: +1 for the permanent (good idea) but -1 because your example doesn't kill the query string or redirect everything under the old domain like he requested.